# Would icon and font library questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am looking for a specific icon/font library with icons related to accommodation.

To be specific, I need hotel related icons that differentiate single-bed, double-bed, bed-sofa, etc., in `.png`, `.jpg` or `.gif` format. With preference to vector formats, paid or not.

Would such questions be on topic here?

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about a library ***dealing with icons and fonts*** (i.e. a *programming library*), the answers given in the more generic [Is it alright to ask for programming tools?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/185) apply: Yes, if put correctly.

But if you're talking about "library" in the sense of "a collection containing fonts and icons", that's a different thing altogether: then you're not looking for "software", but for *content* – which makes the question off-topic.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how a set of icons is a programming tool, could you expand your answer with more details? ;)

Comment: No, that thread discusses “code library containing code to support icons/fonts/…”, but here we're talking about an icon library, as in a collection of images.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the question – sorry for that! Thanks at @Gilles for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 4):

Icons, fonts, images, and other forms of data are on-topic at OpenData:

http://opendata.stackexchange.com

In your question, make sure to mention what kind of license you need. Any open license is OK.

Comment: Nice suggestion, thank you Nicolas