# Where do questions about software development software belong to?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do they belong here or to SO?

- Software development tools (IDEs, VCSs)
- Libraries

Comment: For libraries, see the new Area 51 site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations  "Proposed Q&A site for programmers seeking the best library for specific tasks". As to tools, I guess the best place is here. "Opinion based" questions, or even the sniff of then, very quickly excite the wrath of the downvoters on S.O and programmers these days.

Answer (score 10):

If you are looking for **recommendations** for software development tools and libraries, *Software Recommendations* is the [right place](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools). (Note that recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow and most of the other SE sites.)

If you have a question about (the usage of, a problem with, …) specific libraries and "software tools commonly used by programmers", *Stack Overflow* might be the right place.

Questions about the not-so-much-programming-related usage of software development tools (like installation, configuration, …), might also be on-topic on *Super User* and specialized sites like *Unix & Linux*, *Ask Ubuntu*, etc.

Comment: +1 I use SO when I have questions pertaining to IDEs or VCS, never saw anyone complain except one guy one day who emitted some doubts without it was within SO scope. According to the SO on-topic page, it is.

Comment: Still a bit unclear to me. Where would this one belong: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/advice-on-which-framework-to-use-to-develop-for-osx-and-windows-desktop

Comment: @JanDoggen: I’d say the question (according to title and OP’s motivation) would be on-topic here, but the body contains a question that is not suitable for SR (changing focus from "Which framework should I use?" to "How do frameworks work?") -- however, this is just my guess, I’m not experienced with this topic. If you are unsure about it, maybe ask a separate question here on Meta? (tag: [meta-tag:specific-question])

Comment: @Unor I wrote a separate question, then deleted it because of the large overlap with this one ;-) - thought it would be more useful as an illustration to this question. Yes, that last sentence makes it ambiguous. On second thoughts, I can edit the question to make it more on-topic. On my way now...

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic as there are a lot of questions here that might be better there.